Oracle SOA 12c - receiving two different type of request in the same service
We have received a requirement to receive two differenty type of message (different xsd) in the same bpel service.
I am unsure how to achieve this and did some studying but unable to figure this out.
Would appreciate if anyone has any pointer or suggestion.
Apologies for not having too much details on the requirement.
Thanks in Advance
